Excel Pivot-Table - Different Number-formats in one Column
i have a column in the source data, which contains different userdefined Numberformats, like
#
# "a"
# "b"

These Formats get lost when showing in PivotTable.
e.g.
SourceData
8
25
7 b
11
12 a

which leads to the Pivot Table
8
7
11
12
25

Is there a way to maintain each single Numberformat?
I tried conditional formating, but failed because of different sorting and filtering of Source and Pivot Data.
thanks in advance

Change your source data to contain the proper value. Then you can format both the source and the pivot to display the desired suffix depending on the actual value.

thanks, my example wasn´t good, i reformulated it.
in my case, "ng" and "mg" have nothing to do with each other, so i cannot multiply or divide in order to get the same physical unit.

AFAIK, there is no way to have different number formats for different cells in an Excel pivot table column. You will probably need a different method to display whatever it is you want to display.

I feel this is an x, y issue. Why are you storing data in a column that has no relation to the other data in that column and what are you trying to get out of pivoting it? If it is Qty and Unit Measure they should be in separate columns, formatting isn't really data.

@Ron: ok, thanks. i feared that, but in this case i will have to split the data, add a new column and adjust the PivotTable ⏱

@Warcupine: U are completely right. We had a change in incoming data and in order to keep the same structure, i wanted to cheat in one column into the Numberformat. But if different formats arent allowed, as Ron says, i´ll have to choose another way. Nevertheless, thanks man
